# Why can't I add a computer part to my generic order?

Tags: java, generics

When I try to compile I get recompile with -Xlint unchecked for details. When I run it says: "T extends Product declared in class GenericOrder.

I thought "T" meant I could shove any product in my array. My array also does not give an orderID. I like to check things before moving forward but I can't figure out how to create a GenericOrder with some computer parts.

```
abstract class Product {
    protected float price;

    // return the price of a particular product
    abstract float price();
}

class ComputerPart extends Product {
    public ComputerPart(float p) {
        price = p;
    }

    @Override
    public float price() {
        return price;
    }
}

class GenericOrder<T> {
    private static int ID = 0;
    private String orderID;
    List<T> order;

    public GenericOrder() {
        orderID = "order ID " + ID++;
        order = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getOrderID() {
        return orderID;
    }

    public void addToOrder(T newProduct) {
        order.add(newProduct);
    }

    public List<T> getProducts() {
        return order;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        GenericOrder  order = new GenericOrder ();
        order.getOrderID();
        order.addToOrder(new ComputerPart(5));
        order.getProducts();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. indent your code. 2. Post the exact and complete messages from the compiler instead of paraphrasing them. 3. Don't use raw types (that's probably what the warning is telling you). GenericOrder is generic, so you should dpecify its generic type.

Comment: `GenericOrder order` - don't use raw types. Use `GenericOrder<ComputerPart>`.

Comment: (as a side note, don't use `float` for prices, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Comment: *Curious:* What is the point of calling `getOrderID()` and `getProducts()` when you don't use the return values?

Answer (score 2):

In your `main` simply specify type of the generic:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    GenericOrder<ComputerPart> order = new GenericOrder<>();
    order.getOrderID();
    order.addToOrder(new ComputerPart(5));
    order.getProducts();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>` does *not* mean that the list can store anything. It means that the list can store `T`, and `T` can be any one type. For example, if `T` is `Integer`, `List<T>` can only store integers.

The problem here is that `GenericOrder` is a generic type. Generally when you use generic types, you specify all the generic arguments, but you didn't:

```
GenericOrder  order = new GenericOrder ();
```

In this case, the compiler treats this as having a generic parameter of `Object`. This means that the inner list can store `Object`s or anything that extends `Object`. This is clearly not what you wanted. Therefore, you should add the generic arguments to say that you want a `GenericOrder` of `ComputerPart`:

```
GenericOrder<ComputerPart> order = new GenericOrder<>();
```